# When a container element is filled with inline elements, how does the browser decide between starting a new line or extending the container?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I've got a container element, whose line is almost filled with `inline` or `inline-block` elements and can't hold another inline element, without resize.

[image]

How is the browser supposed to decide whether it can resize the container, extending it and putting the new `inline` element into the same line, or whether it should break the line and put the new `inline` element below the existing elements?

If either `width` or `max-width` attributes are set for the container element or its parents, it's pretty straightforward, but what if neither of those are set?

Moreover, I'm interested in one special case: if the container element is a direct descendant of `body` or `HTML`, when would container element overflow the `HTML` element's size and cause the browser to draw scrollbar:

[image]

If I don't take any special measures, overflow beyond browser's viewport usually doesn't take place; instead, the browser inserts line breaks. I wonder why and how to force the browser to increase width of my container element upon addition of inline elements, without explicitly specifying `width`, `min-width`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look on the screenshot below:

[image: DEMO]

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/vKbts)

`.container{display: inline-block; width: auto}` provides you with the flexible container width to fit in all the elements. The container here is treated as `<span>`

`.container{display: block;width: auto}` provides you with full width container as the default behaviour.

`.container{display: block; width: 250px}` provides you with confined container. Anything that do not fit in will automatically gets line break.

`.container{display: block; width: 250px; white-space: nowrap}` the `white-space: nowrap` is the css property that allows the container not to add `\n` to the elements.

`.container{display: block; width: 250px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap}` finally, the `overflow-x: auto` gives you the opportunity to have a native scrollbar. Usually, `overflow: auto` should suffice in most browsers.

A couple notes:
-Zooming does not affect the behaviour of the container since when the page is zoomed, both container and elements will be zoomed thus they get scaled together and no extra space will be added/removed.
-The `search container` in stackoverflow has fixed margin and position. This will not affect how the elements inside the container should behave. They have been told to stay there no matter how much spaces are available. To fix this, one could use `@media screen` css property to re-arrange the position of the elements in the header of the stack overflow.

Comment: raunay, thank you for your elaborate answer, but may be I was not clear enough, explaining the emphasis of my question. In your code example, change the width of `.inline-element` from 100 to 400 pixels. You'll notice, that first 3 samples will insert line breaks in order to fit into browser window and display some `inline-elements` on a second line, while the last 2 samples won't. My main point was that I don't understand, what makes the browser behave that way (insert line breaks to fit into window) and how to force it draw all `inline-elements` in a single line, creating a scrollbar?

Comment: The browser behave that way in the first two examples because of the default css property `white-space: normal`. This tells the user that if the container does not have enough space for the inline element, add line break to it.

It forces to draw `inline-element` in single line due to the css property `white-space: nowrap`. Try to delete that property in `.container-element-2` or `.container-element-3`, and you will find that it will add line breaks to the elements.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't specify `width`, it actually has a default value of `auto`. Basically this means that the element will take up all the available space of its parent (for block elements) or the width of its content (for inline-block).

Weather or not the container is a descendant of body or html doesn't really make a difference. These elements also both have a default width of auto. Because html doesn't technically have a parent element, it takes up all the space it can.. which happens to be the browser's window. So, a horizontal scrollbar will only appear if an element's width is explicitly defined as being wider than its parent. (although you can control this behavior with the `overflow` property.

My explanation may not be entirely correct, but I hope it helps you a bit.

Comment: zooming is a completely separate issue. What do you mean by it taking up more space than the screen? It is set to `width: 100%;` and should span the width of your browser window. The main content area f stackoverflow is set to a width of 980px.

Comment: Brian, thanks for your answer. I just looked at stackoverflow's topbar as an example. If you zoom in, it obviously takes up more space, than screen allows, but instead of wrapping a line, and putting topbar-links `div` under network-items `div`, browser creates a scrollbar. Why does it do so? In other sites body isn't allowed to overflow `html`'s width.

Comment: I mean that `search container` floats beyond the edge of viewport, if you zoom in, while it could've been wrapped to the next line. Why?  Does it happen so, because of 980px `width` of main area (namely, header `div` and content `div`), causing `body` to have `width` of  980px + something, so that `topbar`'s `width`=100% of body's `width`= 980px+something? But I can disable `header`'s and `content`'s `width` setting and topbar still overflows, not wraps line.

Comment: Zooming zooms the container too. The scrollbar is probably created by the some ancestor of inline elements.